# Reflection, .net project reading dll from .net core project in a different solution

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core

I've got 2 solutions in visual studio 2017.

- The first solution has a project that reads an assembly/dll from a project in an external solution. This project is coded in .net 4.5.2
- The second solution has a project that with the targeted classes/dll to reflect to the first project. This project is written in .net core 2
- Both projects are in 2 different solutions.

Code in the first project:

```
string pathDllProject_DAL = "E:\\Coding\\Repos\\_order_manager_webapp\\order_manager_webapp_backend\\DAL\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.2\\DAL.dll";
//This line of code works, I do get the assembly object
Assembly ass_DAL2 = Assembly.LoadFile(pathDllProject_DAL);


Type[] respTypes = ass_DAL2.GetTypes(); //<----Exception Thrown HERE
```

This is the exception i get:

```
'ass_DAL2.GetTypes()' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146232830
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    LoaderExceptions: {System.Exception[152]}
    Message: "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."
    Source: "mscorlib"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()\r\n   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()"
    TargetSite: {System.RuntimeType[] GetTypes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule)}
    Types: {System.RuntimeType[279]}
```

I was wondering if there is an incompatibility in reading a DLL created in .net-core from a .net 4.5.2 framework? or is there some other issue?

Comment: `Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.` Did you do that?

Comment: @thehennyy is it suggesting that the type data laoded from the dll is not compatible?

Comment: Then that is your answer.

Comment: @thehennyy so the only solution is to rewrite the Dll reader project as a .net.core project?

Comment: Well that depends on your use-case. There a libraries that can read both types of files, but then the code they contain is not executable. Have a look at `dnlib`.

Comment: @thehennyy I'd rather not risk any other compatibility exception, I'll rewrite the code in .net-core. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering of there is an incompatibility in reading a DLL created in .net-core from a .net 4.5.2 framework?

It is. A .NET Framework application cannot reference .NET Core assemblies and vice versa. That's why there is the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

A .NET Standard project can be referenced from both a .NET Framework application as well as a .NET Core app.

Comment: What can I do, can I create the first project (the project tha reads the external dll) as a .net standard project? Or the only way is to re write the project in .net-core?

Comment: @Luther: Whether you can convert your code to .NET Standard depends on the APIs you are using and the compability you want. Please refer to the matrix on the link I posted for an overview of the .NET versions that support each .NET Standard version. Also note that .NET Standard is not a runtime but a specification.

Comment: yes, unfortunately I've read it and there is no compatibility, I need to rewrite the code in .net-core. Thanks